# PowerShell equivalent of linux less command implemented as a powershell function

Tags: powershell

I know that I can get a function similar to linux less command by doing the following at the PowerShell prompt:

```
PS> cat really_long_file.txt | out-host -Paging
```

How can I make it look like this instead:

```
PS> cat really_long_file.txt | less
```

I was thinking of two approaches that might work.

1. Define an alias for "out-host" called "less", then set the default parameter of "less" to "-paging".  Now really sure how to do this.

```
Set-Alias -Name less -Value out-host
#set default params for less???
```

2. Define a function called "out-host" that take pipe input and sends it to "out-host -paging". Not really sure how to do this either. I tried the following that doesn't work:

```
filter less {$_ | out-host -paging}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PS> set-alias -name less -value out-paging
PS> $PSDefaultParameterValues['out-page:paging'] = $true

PS> cat really_long_file.txt | out-paging
```